# Creating users in cpanel

Tags: user-management, users

We have recently purchased VPS server hosting and manage it through a WHM cpanel interface. There are many users who need to access this and all of them currently use it through the root login. However, I want to be able to create multiple users, each having root access privileges but different usernames and password so that it is clear as to which user logged on and performed different tasks. Please can anyone point me to any resources or links on how this can be achieved. Thanks

Comment: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/ResellersIntro

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

mailq's comment has instructions on how to do this ( http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/ResellersIntro )

Something to keep in mind, unless you have something set up to log actions to a completely different server, if you actually give root privileges to an account they will be able to remove the logs of their actions which is something not everyone thinks about.

If there is a potential trust issue involved in this, seriously consider whether you even need to give out full root access.  Many tasks can be accomplished with a combination of giving all privileges but root, APIs, and the proper use of setuid/setgid.